# Base64-to-PNG converted images are not showing

Tags: laravel, image

I am totally new in APIs and I am trying to store Base64 images in PNG format in a database as well as in a directory. And its working well without any issue. But when I am opening the image it's showing me that it's not supported this format.

Here is my code:

```
$image = $request->image;  // Your base64 encoded
$image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', "", $image);
$image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
$imageName = time().'.png';

Storage::disk('local')->put($imageName, base64_decode($image));
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$imageName = time().'.png';
$decoded = base64_decode($request->image);
Storage::disk('local')->put($imageName, $decoded);
```

Comment: image is storing but on opening showing, this format is not supported

Comment: How are you opening the image, where do you see the "format is not supported" error? Have you tried with various different images?

Comment: I have tried to open it in photos, paint and also on chrome

Comment: Are you sure it's a .png, have you tried changing the extension to .jpg ? Have you tried different images or just this one file?

Comment: Have you tried using your base64 string here https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter ?

Comment: Also, I have uploaded different images by converting images to base64 online

Comment: on your above link, i have tried and its showing the image,  I have checked the same image that I am storing using POSTMAN

Comment: I am converting my image in base64 format from here https://www.base64-image.de/  and then storing it using Postman, and it stores successfully but images are not showing on preview

Comment: Do you have any other solution, please help. I am totally trapped in it.

Comment: Have you tried with several different images? When you say "its showing the image" - download it to your machine and see if you can open it there. Other than that I'm out of ideas sorry!

Comment: I have downloaded and its visible, but the images I am uploading is not visible,